# python multiline command running from bash

Tags: python, bash

I'm trying to run this:

```
python -c "for i in range(10):\n  print i"
```

but I get an error:

```
File "<string>", line 1
for i in range(10):\n  print i
                             ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

According to [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html) I assume that `bash` should have processed (namely, newline symbol) command line arguments but the returned error shows the opposite case. Where am I wrong, and why does this happen?

P.S. python-2.7

**EDIT**

Let me explain my motivation a bit.
This code example is definitely pretty silly. Since [the doc](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html) says that "`command` can be one or more statements separated by newlines, with significant leading whitespace as in normal module code", I was interested in how should I bring those mentioned newlines to the `command` properly.
The proposed solutions here are:

1. Use `;` to distinguish several commands inside the loop. Yes, that works but it still is a *one-liner*, I can not use it If I want to run some commands *after* the loop. `;` is not a replacement for a newline.
2. Type `^M` where newline is needed. This hits the goal more precisely but unfortunately, to my point of view, this basically ruins the whole idea of running a python code from the command line because it requires interactive mode. As I understand it's the same as entering a command ant hitting `Enter` key. So no difference to typing `python` and working in its shell. That said, I cannot write this in a bash script. Or may I?

Probably the question really should have been splitted into two ones:

1. Bash escaping:

   > Enclosing characters in double quotes (‘"’) preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of ‘$’, ‘`’, ‘\’, and, when history expansion is enabled, ‘!’. The characters ‘$’ and ‘`’ retain their special meaning within double quotes (see Shell Expansions). The backslash retains its special meaning only when followed by one of the following characters: ‘$’, ‘`’, ‘"’, ‘\’, or newline.

How does this correspond to the case described? How does bash handles newlines? I found that putting the command into unary quotes makes no change.

2. How to pass a newline to python in a non-interactive way. (You may say -- why don't you write an ordinary python file with all newlines you want -- you are right but I'm interested in what is exactly meant in the documentation since it quotes newline)

Comment: What version of python are you running?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You actually would need to transform the `\n` part into an actual newline. That can be done with the `$''` syntax:

```
python -c $'for i in range(10):\n  print i'
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

You can also reach that result with `echo -e` or `printf`

```
$ python -c "$(echo -e "for i in range(10):\n  print i")"
```

You could also use a here string:

```
$ python <<< $(echo -e "for i in range(10):\n  print i")
```

See section [3.1.2.4 ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting) of the Bash Manpage for more information.

Answer (score 4):

Remove `\n`

```
python -c "for i in range(10):  print i"
```

Or

You can use `;` for using  multiple line in for loop

```
python -c "for i in range(10): print '1st newline';print '2nd newline';print i"
```

Comment: This surely doesn't answer the question. Your proposal makes the command a one-liner

Comment: Why you are using new line?

Comment: This is just lightweight working example that simulates the problem, the actual code is a bit more complex and it needs and it needs to be multiline.

Comment: You can use `;` for using multiple line in for loop

Answer (score 1):

You can run a multi-line python -c statement by adding CR characters in your line:

```
python -c "for i in range(10):^M print (i)^M print ('Hello:' + str(i*i))"
```

where ^M is not actually ^ followed by M, it is actually the character you get when you type [CTRL-v][CTRL-m].  Notice the space after this character, which means there are two print statements in the for loop, and it should print:

```
0
Hello:0
1
Hello:1
....
9
Hello:81
```

You can do this in a bash script too:

```
#!/bin/bash
A="python -c \"for i in range(10):^M print (i)^M print ('Hello:' + str(i*i))\""
eval $A
```