# python3 -c with long cmd string: Trying to resolve invalid syntax

Tags: python, macos, bash, command-line

I know it would be easier if I put a long python script within a file, but I am trying to resolve why I am having a syntax error when within a `python3 -c cmd`:

FYI: If it matters, I am performing this on OS X.

I read the following, but it did not resolve my problem:
[python multiline command running from bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33368897/python-multiline-command-running-from-bash)

This is the working python3 script if executed from within a file:

```
import csv

with open('tmp/google_adwords_report.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    csvfile.seek(0)
    next(csvfile)
    readCSV = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in readCSV:
        print(row)
```

And this is the same script if performed within command line `python3 -c cmd`:

```
$ python3 -c "import csv;  with open('tmp/google_adwords_report.csv', 'r') as csvfile: csvfile.seek(0); next(csvfile);  readCSV = csv.DictReader(csvfile); for row in readCSV: print(row);"

  File "<string>", line 1
    import csv;  with open('tmp/google_adwords_report.csv', 'r') as csvfile: csvfile.seek(0); next(csvfile);  readCSV = csv.DictReader(csvfile); for row in readCSV: print(row);
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thanks

Comment: Based on the link you provided, you aren't exactly following the instructions in the working solution. I followed them and the only issue I had before getting it to work were indentation issues, which wasn't surprising. I tried out spacing accordingly after each`\n` and I got it working. By working...I did not receive a syntax error. That is all I checked as far as functionality.

Comment: Unrelated but  `csvfile.seek(0)` is a noop, the pointer is already at the start of the file, also if you exec the line in an ide you will get the same error. I got it working correctly by adding tabs and newlines where necessary

Comment: @idjaw I tried: `python3 -c "import csv\n\nwith open('tmp/google_adwords_report.csv', 'r') as csvfile:\n\tnext(csvfile)\n\treadCSV = csv.DictReader(csvfile)\n\tfor row in readCSV:\n\t\tprint(row)"`,   and I got 
_SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character_

Comment: @JeffTanner That means your spacing after the new lines is still off. This did not give me a syntax error: http://pastebin.com/WPPaFKEx

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Good point about the `csvfile.seek(0)`.

Comment: @jeff  try http://pastebin.com/F9tWHbW7 from a bash shell, your code above would also have worked if you used single quotes for the string itself and double quotes for the file name.

Comment: If you echo both versions you will see a difference, the \tand \n are not interpreted properly unless you use single quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are limited by what is allowed in Python on a single line.  See the Compound Statements section of the Python Language Ref for more info.

Basically, some things are not allowed.  For example:

```
python -c "if (1): print(1)"
```

is okay.  But:

```
python -c "if (1): if (1): print(1)"
```

is not allowed.

Another thing, you can't combine a statement with a indented clause.  So, this is also not okay:

```
python -c "print(1); if (1): print(1)"
```

And that's the issue you are running into.

If you're in a shell that supports continuation of strings, you could do:

```
# python3 -c "if (1):
>   if (1):
>     print(1)
> "
1
```

Another thing that may work for you is inline CRs (via ^V^M).  For example:

```
# python3 -c "if (1):^M  if (1):^M    print(1)"
1
```

That is, I actually typed in CTRL-V CTRL-M to create the ^M.

And, I am on OS X as well (Mavericks), running from bash.

Answer (score 1):

Tyring to do this in a single line is wasting your time, and will cause you grief when you need to make a change to your code. This would be true in any language, but is especially so due to Python's whitespace requirements.

Just use a [heredoc](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html):

```
python3 << EOF
import csv

with open('tmp/google_adwords_report.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    csvfile.seek(0)
    next(csvfile)
    readCSV = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in readCSV:
        print(row)
EOF
```